# Solving a non-homogenous system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> If X' = AX + b then can I use the same principle as if this was an first order ODE?

What do I mean by that, to solve a first order ODE we multiply with the so-called integrating factor: $e^{-\int a(t)dt}$ can I apply this here and solve it this way?

So what would I do:

$$X'-AX=b$$

multiply both sides with $e^{-At}$

$$(Xe^{-At})'=be^{-At}$$

integrate both sides

$$Xe^{-At}=\int be^{-At}dt$$

Giving us:

$$X=e^{At}\int be^{-At}dt$$

Where $A \in \mathcal M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Is this proof correct? How do I integrate a Matrix or a vector? Do I integrate on every component? Also how do I raise $e$ to some matrix power? Do I use the fact that:

$$e^{At}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(At)^n}{n!}$$

And if $A$ is diagonalizable I can:

$$e^{At}=P(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(Dt)^n}{n!})P^{-1}$$

Now:

$$e^{At}=Pe^{Dt}P^{-1}$$

where: $D$ is a diagonal matrix, but still how do I compute $e^{Dt}$?

And what if $A$ is not diagnolaziable and it's root are complex, conjugate?

How can I solve then?

Comment: Did you review something like https://math.berkeley.edu/~conway/Teaching/old/summer2016-2552bc/exercises/NonhomoSys.pdf and https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/4233/4233-l03.pdf and https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~novozhil/Teaching/266%20Data/lecture_24.pdf?

Comment: No, but can you exaplin me in more details what *really* happens when you raise $e$ to a matrix?

Comment: Sure, read this - http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf

Comment: Your proof is formally correct although it doesn't make much sense if you don't know about the matrix exponential. For the integral of a vector-valued function, you integrate each entry, yes. For the calculation of the matrix exponential see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In general you use the Jordan normal form $J$ of $A$, $A = P J P^{-1}$. The matrix $J$ can be written as $J = D + N$ with a diagonal matrix $D$ (containing the eigenvalues of $A$) and with a nilpotent matrix $N$ ($N=0$ if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable). From the power series definition of the exponential function which you already wrote down we obtain
\begin{equation}
e^{tA} = P e^{tJ} P^{-1} = P e^{t(D+N)} P^{-1} = P e^{tD} e^{tN} P^{-1}.
\end{equation}
Now the matrix exponentials $e^{tD}$ and $e^{tN}$ are easy to evaluate:

1.
\begin{equation}
e^{tD} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(tD)^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!} D^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!} \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
d_1^k\\
& d_2^k\\
& & \ddots\\
& & & d_n^k
\end{array}
\right) = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(td_1)^k}{k!}\\
& \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(td_2)^k}{k!}\\
& & \ddots\\
& & & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(td_n)^k}{k!}
\end{array}
\right) = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
e^{td_1}\\
& e^{td_2}\\
& & \ddots\\
& & & e^{td_n}
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation}
2. For the matrix exponential of the nilpotent matrix $N$, which by definition satisfies $N^k = 0$, $k \geq m$, for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, you simply obtain a *finite sum* of powers of $tN$,
\begin{equation}
e^{tN} = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{(tN)^k}{k!}.
\end{equation}
Finally you compute the product $e^{tA} = P e^{tD} e^{tN} P^{-1}$.

By the way all of this also works for complex-valued entries, there is no difference.